# IE8 max-height in percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, web

So I am trying to use the CSS hack to set the max-height for a div in IE8 like this

```
height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 333 ? "333px" : "auto" );
```

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to change that to a percentage, instead of a fixed pixel size?  It would be fantastic if you could.  Thanks!

Basically, I just want to say if `this.scrollHeight is > window.height * .75` or something.

-Geoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to accomplish but it can be done without javascript like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KFyM4/6/

The trick is this:

```
max-height:33%;height:auto !important;height:33%;
```

And it works even in IE6. The only catch is that the parent element has to have a fixed height set so that it knows from what number to calculate the %.

So if you are doing it on browser window you will have to get the height of window and apply it to your `body` trough javascript - rest can be done trough css.

Comment: Ah ok, that actually looks not too bad.  Will give it a crack to see if it works.